# Share App Service Plan between Logic Apps and Azure App Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I'm developing custom connectors that wraps some App Functions in order to be used from Logic Apps. The Logic Apps will be of type Standard (with a plan associated to them) and the Azure Functions will be of type App Service Plan.

The only plans available to pick in the Logic Apps are WS1, WS2 and WS3.

All the resources are related and I'd like to save costs with only one service plan. ¿It is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried? Seriously, that’s all I’d be doing to try and answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible.

Although both plans appear in the subscription as type "App service plan", you cannot choose the 'Function' App service plan (in my case an S1) when creating a logic app, nor can you choose the 'Logic app' App Service plan (in my case an WS1) when creating a new function app.